# Cómo agregar una columna a una tabla en Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo que agregar una columna a una tabla de Oracle. Probé todas las formas.

Quizá en la sintaxis estaría mal, no sé.

Un ejemplo de lo que probé es:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN INGRESOS_BRUTOS NUMBER(8,2);
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un detalle muy importante en la instrucción SQL: el nombre de la tabla que quieres modificar:

```
ALTER TABLE <nombre de tabla>
    ADD COLUMN INGRESOS_BRUTOS NUMBER(8,2);
```

Donde `<nombre de tabla>` debería ser el nombre de la tabla que quieres modificar. Si ésta se llama (por ejemplo) `mitabla`, entonces deberías teclear:

```
ALTER TABLE mitabla ADD COLUMN INGRESOS_BRUTOS NUMBER(8,2);
```

Una vez que introduzcas el nombre de la tabla debería funcionarte correctamente.